# PrincipalContext for query in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, principalcontext

I want to make a few simple reports from Active Directory. Following discussions, etc. I found that if I use .NET FW 3.5 and up, it is appropriate to use `PrincipalContext`. I would like to understand principles and what I can do with this new feature (unlike `DirectoryEntry`).

**Code skeleton**

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
    "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=SomeOU,DC=YourCompany,DC=com");

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// which has a password that will expire in 3 days or less
UserPrincipal userTemplate = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
userTemplate.AdvancedSearchFilter.AccountExpirationDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(3), MatchType.LessThanOrEquals);

// instantiate searcher
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userTemplate);

// enumerate matching users
foreach (Principal foundPrincipal in searcher.FindAll())
{
    UserPrincipal foundUser = (foundPrincipal as UserPrincipal);

    if (foundUser != null)
    {
        // do something with users found - e.g. send e-mail
    }
}
```

It is possible by code up add this properties for login to LDAP?:

- what LDAP is used (version 2 or 3)
- how set port on which LDAP is running
- how to work if I need SSL connection? (different port, must be special requirements)

Furthermore, can I do with `AdvancedSearchFilter` this conditions?
(I found only `AccountExpirationDate` and `AccountLockoutDate`)

- users password will expire in the near future
- users password has expired
- check if the user's password can expire
- users account expires (account, no password)
- expired users account (account, no password)
- user account not expired

Comment: If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (and which answers a lot of your questions, I believe)

Comment: Hello, thank for link to article, i I read and I tried test codes in addition to AD, but unfortunately, I'm still in almost the same situation. Eg. when I lock user account, state of  "IsAccountLockedOut" property is always False, if I set the account expiration date, AccountLockoutTime property is never set, etc. In addition, many other properties are not under the user at all in class UserPrincipal. I probably not understand the philosophy why to use PrincipalContext instead of DirectoryEntry.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. The error will be between the chair and the keyboard, I really did not understand the principle. Once I have a result, I will send the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the late reply. The solution I found these two links, which describes all the information. Just as it only needs to combine with the code above.

[retrieve the value of "Minimum Password Length" in domain password policy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8bf326d9-16b8-47a3-8916-7af41e8b1121)

[House of Derek - Password expiration email utility](http://houseofderek.blogspot.cz/2008/07/password-expiration-email-utility.html)